# Why my login form in python is not working properly?

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, bcrypt, flask-login, csrf-token

I have a problem with a Login Form. I used Flask and Bcrypt.

When i try to login, with a user and password, the login page is not returning anything, i stay in the same login page, the only difference is the url returns this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?csrf_token=IjgwZTRhZmI4NWM2MTExNTdiM2I1NmM2YTYzZjIxZTdhMmI4M2JkZTgi.YYwLuQ.bYG6VKjMZ65p4i86S9-U23L9c_A&username=alexcar&password=1234Ab&submit=Login
```

This is the login form def:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('admin'))  
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

When the user is authenticated returns the page admin, in Def admin is:

```
@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def admin():
    return render_template('admin.html')
```

On Login.html form is:

```
<div class="form-floating">
      <form action="" method="post">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ form.username }}
      <br> </br>
     {{ form.password }}
    {{ form.submit }}
      </form>
    </div>
```

The register form is working well but the login page not.

Comment: Please note, that you have shared a local address in your post. Other people will only be able to see what you see, if they have the exact same local setup as you do.

Comment: Thanks. Now the platform is on local access on my computer, i testing the app

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your return statement after signing in.
Note: The url_for takes in the name of the route function (def admin) not (def .admin)

```
return redirect(url_for('.admin'))
```

should be:

```
return redirect(url_for('admin'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried 'admin' without the dot before and not works. When i use the login form the errors is the same. I keep in the login page and in the url appears http://localhost:5000/?csrf_token=IjgwZTRhZmI4NWM2MTExNTdiM2I1NmM2YTYzZjIxZTdhMmI4M2JkZTgi.YYwLuQ.bYG6VKjMZ65p4i86S9-U23L9c_A&username=alexcar&password=1234Ab&submit=Login